# Pandas: Drop duplicates using date.dt.day as a subset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Background

I am looking at the corona virus dataset from **CSSEGISandData**: github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19.git.
The data is **stored in csv divided by day** (eg: 01-24-2020.csv,  01-25-2020.csv,  01-26-2020.csv).

I have concatenated all the files into one pandas dataframe, however there are **duplicates present** as you can **see below with Sweden**. This happens becuase when the data for sweden is not updated, the next day file reports the Last Update (thus the last data).

```
             Province/State        Country/Region   Last Update    Confirmed
2229             Tibet        Mainland China 2020-02-01 01:52:40        1.0   
2990           Ningxia        Mainland China 2020-02-01 02:13:00       26.0   
3025               NaN                Sweden 2020-02-01 02:13:00        1.0   #THIS
3023               NaN                 Spain 2020-02-01 02:13:00        1.0   
1847               NaN                Sweden 2020-02-01 02:13:26        1.0   #THIS
5910               NaN                Sweden 2020-02-01 02:13:26        1.0   #THIS
2232               NaN                Sweden 2020-02-01 02:13:26        1.0   #THIS
```

## Objective

I want to:

1. Subset data based on Province/State
2. If Province/State is NaN --> Use Country/Region (eg: Sweden)
3. Drop all duplicates within the subsets based on 'Last update' Date precise to the day (excluding hour in case there is more than one result form the same day
4. return the Dataframe

To adress 1 and 2, i have filled the NaN of Province/State with the Country/Region value. Howver this isn't ideal, i would prefer to be able to not fill the NaN.

This is my code so far, however i am not able to drop the duplicates.

```py
!git clone https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19.git

#@title Import files csse_covid_19_data { form-width: "10px" }
import pandas as pd 
import glob
path = r'/content/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv") #collect all files in one

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    df['file']=filename[-14:]
    li.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False) #one dataframe 


frame['Province/State'].fillna(frame['Country/Region'], inplace=True) #putting the Coutry in teh NaN of Province for data cleanup 

#change the 'Last Update'] to datetime format
frame['Last Update'] = pd.to_datetime(frame['Last Update'])
frame = frame.sort_values(by="Last Update")
```

### EDIT: Curret solution from:  FROM YOBEN_S

This is the current solution, it works but i am am filling the Province/state with the Country/Region, instead of grouping on Country region when Province state is NaN

```
frame = frame.assign(day=frame['Last Update'].dt.date).\
          drop_duplicates(subset=(['day', 'Province/State'])).drop('day',axis=1)
```

Ideally i want to **drop_duplicates** using the date and Province/State as subsets, but when Province/State is NaN switch to Country Region

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust you last row

```
#Since NaN ==NaN return False, so 
frame.fillna('Not Ava',inplace=True)
frame = frame.assign(day=frame['Last Update'].dt.date).\
          drop_duplicates(subset=(['day', 'Country/Region'])).drop('day',axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, above I also have the issue that some rows dont have 'Province/State' (like Sweden), while grouping on ''Country/Region' doesn't work becuase China has many reports from different areas. Can i modify this code to group 'Province/State' mainly, but on 'Country/Region' if' 'Province/State' is Nan like for Sweden?

Comment: As i understand it, day will now not be able to distinguish between eg:  23/02 and 23/03 as both will be 23. And fillling the NaN with 'Not Ava' doesn't adress the issue of subsetting properely (considering state/provence when possible and Country/region when state provence is NaN)

Comment: @David8 change to dt.date ?

Comment: that will work. I have filled them ''Province/State' NaN with their correspoding 'Country/Region' values. this works however i would prefer not to modify the column. is there a solution you can think of? because i think yours doesn't adress it

Comment: I have edited my question to make it all more clear, the solution as it is in the question works, but I would prefer not to fill the NaN, it seems like a bad Practice

Comment: @David8 then you can not drop_duplicate , since NaN == NaN is False

Answer (score 0):

You can also use boolean indexing:

```
frame[frame['Last Update'].dt.normalize().duplicated() 
      & frame['Country/Region'].duplicated()]
```

Note that `frame['Last Update'].dt.day` only gives you the day in number and ignore year/month. It may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Definitely not, i want the Date then, ignoring the hour, how do i do this?

Comment: Can i use this to adress the issue i added in edit, that when Province is NaN i want to use Country/Region to groupby?